# Is it possible to insert and replace rows with pgloader?

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgloader

My use case is the following: I have data coming from a csv file and I need to load it into a table (so far so good, nothing new here). It might happen that same data is sent with updated columns, in which case I would like to try to insert and replace in case of duplicate.

So my table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE codes (
  code            TEXT NOT NULL,
  position_x      INT,
  position_y      INT
  PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

And incoming csv file is like this:

```
TEST01,1,1
TEST02,1,2
TEST0131,3
TEST04,1,4
```

It might happen that sometime in the future I get another csv file with:

```
TEST01,1,1000 <<<<< updated value
TEST05,1,5
TEST0631,6
TEST07,1,7
```

Right now what is happening is when I run for the first file, everything is fine, but when I execute for the second one I'm getting an error:

```
2017-04-26T10:33:51.306000+01:00 ERROR Database error 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "codes_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (code)=(TEST01) already exists.
```

I load data using:

```
pgloader csv.load
```

And my csv.load file looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV
     FROM 'codes.csv' (code, position_x, position_y)
     INTO postgresql://localhost:5432/codes?tablename=codes (code, position_x, position_y)

     WITH fields optionally enclosed by '"',
          fields terminated by ',';
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with pgloader?

I also tried dropping constrains for the primary key but then I end up with duplicate entries in the table.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. As per [reference](http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html)

> To work around that *(load exceptions, eg PK violations)*, pgloader cuts the data into batches of 25000 rows
> each, so that when a problem occurs it's only impacting that many rows
> of data.

in brackets - mine...

The best you can do is load csv to table with same structure and then merge data with help of query (`EXCEPT`, `OUTER JOIN ... where null` and so on)

Comment: Thx for your answer! Here is some additional info provided by the author with an alternative approach to achieve the desired result explained in the question - https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/540#issuecomment-297372388